# gem --version different to sudo gem --version :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, installation, rvm

I'm a bit of a Linux noob trying to get ruby, rails, mysql and sqlite all playing nicely on ubuntu 10. I am getting errors, and I realized that the versions are different for sudo versus normal user!

```
mpw@ubuntu:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0$ gem --version
1.3.7
mpw@ubuntu:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0$ sudo gem --version
1.3.5
```

I have used RVM to install it, but it seems that I have conflicting versions. How to fix?

Comment: One of the nice things about RVM is that you will most likely *never* need to run gem as the root user, as all your gems are installed within `~/.rvm`.

Comment: I recommend reading the first two entries in the RVM FAQ: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/

Answer (score 0):

`sudo gem --version` most likely is using the system `gem` i.e the one you get when you do `rvm system`. This is because sudo changes user to root and you probably didn't do `sudo rvm use 1.9.2` or something similar. Try doing `sudo which gem` and `which gem` to confirm this.

You can update the version used by root by doing `sudo gem update --system`. However note that you are still most likley using different gem paths when using `sudo gem` and `gem` if you are not using the system gem executable by default i.e `rvm use system`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same installation mistake before, but following these instructions worked. http://ascarter.net/2010/05/10/rails-development-on-ubuntu-10.04.html

Comment: Speaking from experience, it's better to just use RVM and save yourself all the trouble with the Ubuntu packages. Chances are you'd want to run several versions of Ruby anyway, some of them more up-to-date than the ones in the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a

```
sudo which gem
```

resp

```
which gem
```

to get the information *which* gem you are using. 
I second the opinion of [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698878/752076) that most probably you are using different gem versions and paths.